# Dimensional analysis to retrieve constants in formula for PDE solution

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

Consider for example the PDE
$$ \begin{cases} u_{tt}(x,t) - \Delta u(x,t) = 0 , & (x,t) \in \mathbb R^2,\\
u(x,0) = g(x),\\
u_{t}(x,t) = h(x),
\end{cases}
$$
which solution we know can be written with the formula
$$ (*) \qquad \qquad 2u(x,t) = g(x+t) - g(x-t) + \int_{x-t}^{x+t}h. $$

But if a coefficient $c$ appears in the wave equation as in
$$u_{tt} - c^2 \Delta u= 0,$$
I heard that one can obtain the corresponding formula
$$ 2u(x,t) = g(x+ct) - g(x-ct) + \dfrac{1}{c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} h $$
 directly from $(*)$, without doing back again all calculations, with *dimensional analysis*. How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the rule:

> If we have an expression $A+B$ or $A=B$ where $A,B$ are dimensionfull quantities then $A$ and $B$ must have the same units for it to make sense.

Now $x$ has dimension $L$ (length - for example meters) and $t$ has dimension T (time - for example seconds). $c$ has dimensions of $L/T$ (length over time - for example in meters per second) so $ct$ has dimensions of length. Since $c$ is the only dimension-full constant in the problem we need

$$x - t \to x - ct$$

in order for the units of the two terms to match.

Another way to derive this is to start with

$$u_{tt} = c^2\Delta u$$

and define a new $t$ coordinate by $t' = ct$. Then

$$u_{t't'} = \Delta u$$

Now we can use your solution for the equation above to find

$$2u = g(x-t') + \ldots = g(x-ct) + \ldots$$